# Is it possible that the magnitude of the resultant of two equal vectors be equal to the magnitude of either vector?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

*Is it possible that the magnitude of the resultant of two equal vectors be equal to the magnitude of either vector?*

---

- What does this question mean?
- Does the zero vector(null vector) satisfy the above description?

Comment: Do "equal vectors" have the same magnitude *and* direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just asking to find a vector such that $\vec{v} + \vec{v} = \vec{v}$.

We get the equation $2\vec{v} = \vec{v}$ which is only satisfied for, as you said, $\vec{v} = 0$, the null vector.

Edit:
Well more accurately, as it's talking about magnitudes, $|2\vec{v}| = |\vec{v}|$, but the point still stands.